# Comment similar to plt.tight_layout(pad=0)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Does in python exist a command similar to `plt.tight_layout(pad=0)` that would cut the figure more? I tried to set negative argument `pad=-4` , but it didn't worked.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[5,3])
ax = fig.gca(projection = '3d')


ax.set_ylim(0,3)
ax.set_zlim(0,2)
# ax.set_xlim(0,2)

vleng = 5
aleng = vleng/3.

p = np.array([vleng+200, 0, 0])
q = np.array([0, vleng-2, 0])
r = np.array([0, 0, vleng-3])

ax.plot(*np.vstack([[0,0,0], p]).T, color='black')
ax.plot(*np.vstack([[0,0,0], q]).T, color='black')
ax.plot(*np.vstack([[0,0,0], r]).T, color='black')

ax.azim = 20    # y rotation (default=270)
ax.elev = 20    # x rotation (default=0)
ax.dist = 10    # zoom (define perspective)

ax.set_axis_off( )  # hide all grid

plt.tight_layout(pad=0)
plt.show()
```

The desired result:

[image]

Comment: _How could there be cut more than everything between subplots?_ is the question which comes to my mind - that means: [ask] and [mcve] including an example of your wanted result.

Comment: I editted the question

Comment: I'm still not really sure if I understand correctly. But could it be solved by simply decreasing `dist`, e.g. `ax.dist = 5`?

Comment: Thank you it solves the problem. How to do line in this graph? I tried: `plt.plot([0, 1, 1],[0, 1.5, 1.5])` but is connect not the desired points. I am really confuse from coordinates. They rapidly change then I point mause in two closely places.

Comment: According to the SO guidelines this should be another question.

Comment: OK, and is there similar commad to `dist` that will not zoom? I would like to have linewidth same as without using `dist`.

Comment: As far as I can see the linewidth does not change at different `dist` levels.